# Change rule selectorText from JS?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Is it possible to change a `CSSRule`'s `.selectorText` from javascript ? MDN says it is a getter/setter but setting it seems to have no effect...

references :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleRule/selectorText?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FcssRule.selectorText

> selectorText() gets/sets the textual representation of the selector for the rule set.

Edit :
well all the "docs" are wrong and misleading.

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSRule

```
attribute DOMString        selectorText;
                                      // raises(DOMException) on setting
```

Comment: I've edited the MDN wiki to reflect the inconsistency you pointed out. This page still needs some work though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it appears indeed that the browser implementation (at least in Firefox) opts to choose these as readonly (as is apparently allowed per the spec by the fact that `selectorText` (and `cssText` as well) can throw "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: Raised if the rule is readonly.").

You can, however, modify the style property:

```
<style>
body { background-color: darkblue; }
</style>
<p>abc</p>
<script>
  var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0]
  stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.color = 'red'; // Will make body red
</script>
```

You can, however, get by without parsing CSS, by creating and inserting `<style>` tags whose `innerHTML` you set.